# Telerik combobox - viewstate without autopostback

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I turned off `AutoPostback` on my control because I need to validate something with javascript. And if everything is ok I'm doing postback clikcing on hidden button. The problem is that combobox looses selected value on page reloading.`ViewStateMode` set to `Enabled`. I'm populating combobox in page_load event:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    (!IsPostback)
    {                     
        InitializeItems();    // Helper method that binds data
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before going into the internals of Telerik, you can try to resolve the original problem. You said you want to perform validation before the postback takes place.

All you have to do is register the script you want to be ran on form submit:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreRender(e);

    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(typeof(YourClass), this.UniqueID, "your validation script here.");
}
```

Then in order to cancel the postback, your validation script needs to return false.